# How to update aptana 3.3.1?

Tags: version, aptana

I have standalone version of aptana studio (3.3.1) Since then I cannot update. Before it was always automatic. I can see that 3.4.0 version is out.
How to force update?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

go to the *help* menu and select *check for updates*
failing that follow the steps listed at http://d1iwq2e2xrohf.cloudfront.net/tools/studio/plugin/update/studio3-rcp/3.4.0.201304151603/index.html

> **Update Aptana Studio**
>
> 1. From the Help menu, select Install New Software... to open an Install
>      pop-up window.
> 2. In the Work with: text box of the Install window, type
>      the URL http://d1iwq2e2xrohf.cloudfront.net/tools/studio/plugin/update/studio3-rcp/3.4.0.201304151603/ for the update site, and hit the Enter key.
> 3. Close the Install window.
> 4. From the Help menu, select Check for Updates.
> 5. In the new window, click
>      the Next button and then click the Next button again.
> 6. Choose the
>      option to accept the terms of the license agreement, and click the
>      Finish button.

Comment: I've done it - nothing there. Can You give me URL to check for updates? http://preview.appcelerator.com/aptana/studio3/standalone/update/stable/ doesn't work for me and I don't have other...

Comment: here is the details: http://d1iwq2e2xrohf.cloudfront.net/tools/studio/plugin/update/studio3-rcp/3.4.0.201304151603/index.html

Comment: I have error when updating:An error occurred while uninstalling
session context was:(profile=profile, phase=org.eclipse.equinox.internal.p2.engine.phases.Uninstall, operand=[R]com.aptana.feature.rcp_root.win32.win32.x86 3.3.1.201212171919-7o7lFDDFFeFt-ajpeO4csz0uKWjZ --> null, action=org.eclipse.equinox.internal.p2.touchpoint.natives.actions.CleanupzipAction).
Backup of file C:\Program Files (x86)\Aptana\studio3.bat failed.
File that was copied to backup could not be deleted: C:\Program Files (x86)\Aptana\studio3.bat

Comment: Can I uninstall this version and install new one? Every setting would be saved?

Comment: depends on what settings needed to be saved, not 100% sure but you could check their forums.

Comment: I've uninstalled - no settings were saved :/ Thanks form help. In clean install there is that URL http://download.aptana.com/studio3-rcp/plugin/update/ for updates